# ely if there are two catch statements one with exception and another with arithmetic exception which will revoked for an arithmetic exception

Tags: java

If there are two "catch statements" namely one with  general exception and another with   arithmetic exception which will be invoked for an arithmetic exception in the try block??

Comment: What's "general exception"? I think the question would be a lot less ambiguous if you showed us the actual code you're wondering about.

Comment: Please show your code to make your question complete.

Comment: Please add codes before throw your question.

Comment: try { askQuestionWithoutTryingIt(); } catch (NotARealQuestionException e) { close(); }

Answer (score 4):

This is very easy to verify:

```
try {
    int x = 0;
    x = 1 / x;
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    System.err.println("ArithmeticException");
} catch (Exception ee) {
    System.err.println("Another kind of Exception");   
}
```

The above [prints](http://ideone.com/mWMMW6) `ArithmeticException`

That is precisely what is expected to happen: Java will try to catch more specific exceptions before continuing up the chain of inheritance.